# Windows server 2008 IIS 7.5 folder or file cannot be found with +

Tags: windows, iis-7.5, special-folders

My problem is, there is a website on a server:
- Windows server 2008
- IIS 7.5

and there is folder with some image files.

Folder and file name is like this:

```
www.somedomain.com/images/picture+pro/myimage.gif
```

also

```
www.somedomain.com/images/picture/myimage+pro.gif
```

has the same issue.

The issue is; the special char "+" cannot be read on Windows server 2008 with IIS 7.5 but it was read when I developed locally with Visual Studio 2010 on a Windows 7 machine.

Is there some configuration I can make on Windows 2008 or IIS 7.5 to allow reading the folders and/or files that contains "+" character?

Thank you very much

Comment: it is  + .. not %2B  ..  The folder on the server is using +   Also, in the html img src also uses + not %2B

Comment: Why do you expect it to work, then? See [Reserved Characters](http://www.blooberry.com/indexdot/html/topics/urlencoding.htm#whatwhy).

Comment: Because, as I mentioned in my question; It works as it is right now, when I run it locally on Visual Studio 2010.. Also, I tried to write %2B instead of +  on html image src attribute, it didnt work. Also, I tried to change the folder name on the server making + into %2B and it does not work either.

Comment: Don't change it on the server.

Comment: I also tried, ONLY changing the URL from + to %2B and LEAVING the server folder name as  +  without changing. Unfortunately this did not help either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Funny, I hit something like this today when using IIS ARR to reverse proxy a TomCat app running on Windows that uses `+` characters in its urls.

Try allowing `allowDoubleEscaping` on the site. If you have IIS MMC access it's configurable in the Request Filtering applet:

[image]

If not and your hoster permits you can set this in your site's `web.config` file:

```
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <security>
      <requestFiltering allowDoubleEscaping="true">
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Should work if you were getting:

> HTTP Error 404.11 - Not Found
>
> The request filtering module is configured to deny a
>   request that contains a double escape sequence.

Comment: Definitely awesome! Thank you very much. Totally solved my problem!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I was not able to solve this problem on the server, instead I changed the reference names on the related database removing the "+" character.

Therefore, I think it is fair to say that even if the "+" char works on local computer with visual studio's virtual IIS server, it does not mean it'll work on windows server.

I would like to thank ta.speot.is for his effort.